# gxt html select: how to prevent filtering?

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I'd like to create a simple html select using gxt (ideally, using ComboBox). I do not want extra features such as the ability to autocomplete, nor the ability for the user to input some values.

In other words, I don't want the list of items to be ever filtered, it is to always display the full list.

I tried setEditable(false) but it produces some weird bugs, sometimes the list is filtered anyway.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
yourComboBox.setTriggerAction(ComboBoxCell.TriggerAction.ALL);
```